# Drupal AJAX HTTP Request terminated Abnormally after file upload

Tags: drupal

I am getting the following error (as shown) when trying to upload a file to a normal content type. This started happening after migration of the Drupal site to a new server and more than one site hosting on this server seems to be having this problem. Not quite sure what the cause could be at this point.
[image: Drupal AJAX HTTP Request terminated Abnormally]

Comment: How big is the file? The error says Too Large. The new host might not allow huge files.

Comment: File is 14.5MB.....I take note that smaller files of size 3-4MB upload without error. It might be useful to note that I am running Plesk 17.5 ... I also checked to see if mod_security was off and it was....reconfigured it just in case to allow for 64MB files still getting this error...

Comment: The limit might be set in more than one place. In drupal go to reports - status report and beside where it reports the php version there's a link for more information. On that page press CTRL-F and search for upload_max_filesize and also post_max_size (although the second one might not apply in this situation). You can also ask the hoster if they know how to up the limit on that system. If you can't resolve it, upload the file to dropbox or your favorite place and then just post the link to it in the drupal node.

Comment: Is this a CiviCRM question?

Answer (score 2):

Issue was resolved by modifying mod_security configuration